# How to DownLoad The Entire Jquery Website? because want to visit the website and serve this in my localhost server network

Tags: javascript, jquery, vagrant

I want to download the jQuery website in my local machine so i can study the documentation properly even without the internet connection

There is a Guide out there in jQuery website Title [Contributing to jQuery Foundation Web Sites](http://contribute.jquery.org/web-sites/)

i successfully follow the wp-content installation guide with
but I'm struggling at "contribute.jquery.org" `grunt deploy`
its gives me an error

```
E:\jquery-wp-content\contribute.jquery.org>grunt deploy
Loading "build.js" tasks...ERROR
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
Warning: Task "wordpress-deploy" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

how to fix this error | i already tried solution from other overflow question but its not working

and how to add the jquery content in `vagrant.jquery.com`
'this is what ive got'

[image]

jquery web without web content

ive already tried to do download the [jquery.com](https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com) repo ***but theres no guide on how to add and connect it in the child tree of the working wp-content***

and how to fix the issue of clicking the jqueryui tab redirect me to the ssl vagrant site that i did not setup
[image]
, i have to rename it from `https://vagrant.jqueryui.com/` to `http://vagrant.jqueryui.com/` to work

and this one had no content either
[image]

how to add this [jqueryui.com](https://github.com/jquery/jqueryui.com) repository inside of the jquery-wp-content? so i can view the content in my local machine w/out internet?

Comment: it's not strictly what you asked for, but here there's the github for content served by http://api.jquery.com ... it's a wordpress instance and there are more details on its readme: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com

Comment: yea that workflow gives me and error
E:\jquery-wp-content\contribute.jquery.org>grunt deploy Loading "build.js" tasks...ERROR
 ReferenceError: primordials is not defined Warning: Task "wordpress-deploy" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings. 
after i type i enter `'grunt deploy'`

Comment: where should i put the websites content repository after the `contribute.jquery.org`?

Comment: I didn't carefully read the question and I see I just said something redundant. Actually I have no idea how to prepare the instance. I hope you'll get further

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know How to Fix this Problem but You can download jQuery documentation without download the jQuery website on local system by using Zeal Software you can easily download jQuery Documentation and study jQuery offline.

[image]

Download Link: https://zealdocs.org/download.html